# when I'm trying to update my post in swagger I get the folowing error

Tags: php, laravel, http, swagger

> This is my controller and I switched here swagger

```
class ProductController extends Controller

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}


public function getdata()
{
    $products = Product::get();
    return view('table', [
        'products'=>$products
    ]);
}
```

> Here I get all data from database

```
 /**
 * @return array<object string/int>
 *
 *
 * @OA\Get(
 *      path="/api/products",
 *      tags={"Products"},
 *      summary="Get all products",
 *      description="For getting all datas should be pressed the button called 'try'",
 *      operationId="index",
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="paginate",
 *         in="query",
 *         description="Status values that needed to be considered for filter",
 *         required=true,
 *         explode=true,
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *             default="10",
 *             type="string",
 *         )
 *     ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="successful operation",
 *      ),
 *     security={{ "bearer": {} }}
 * )
 */


public function index($paginate=10){
    return UserResource::collection(Product::paginate($paginate));
}
```

> Here I store data from swagger

```
/**
 * @OA\Post(
 *      path="/api/products",
 *      tags={"Products"},
 *      summary="Create a new type of item to the product",
 *      operationId="store",
 *      @OA\RequestBody(
 *          description="Create a new item",
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="multipart/form-data",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  type="object",
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="name",
 *                     description="Give a new name to the product",
 *                     type="string",
 *                 ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="type",
 *                     description="Give a new type to the product",
 *                     type="string",
 *                 ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="price",
 *                     description="Give a new type to the product",
 *                     type="string",
 *                 ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="image",
 *                     description="Give a new type to the product",
 *                     type="file",
 *                 ),
 *              ),
 *          ),
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="successful operation",
 *     ),
 *     security={{ "bearer": {} }}
 * )
*/

public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated();
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
        $product = new Product;
        $product->image = $path;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->type = $request->type;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->save();
    }
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Product created successfully',
        'products' => $product,

    ]);

}
```

> Here I just get the element chosen by id in order to show

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *      path="/api/product/{id}",
 *      tags={"Products"},
 *      summary="Show the choosen element",
 *      operationId="show",
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="id",
 *         in="path",
 *         description="Status values that needed to be considered for filter",
 *         required=true,
 *         explode=true,
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *             default="1",
 *             type="string",
 *         )
 *     ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="successful operation",
 *      ),
 *      security={{ "bearer": {} }}
 * )
 *
 */

public function show($id)
{
    return UserResource::collection(Product::all()->keyBy->id);
}
```

> **Here the error when I try to change existing data in database I get always the error showed below.**

```
/**
 * @OA\Put(
 *      path="/api/product/{id}/update",
 *      tags={"Products"},
 *      summary="Update the choosen element",
 *      operationId="update",
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="id",
 *         in="path",
 *         description="Status values that needed to be considered for filter",
 *         required=true,
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *             type="string",
 *         )
 *     ),
 *      @OA\RequestBody(
 *          description="Update a new item",
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="multipart/form-data",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  type="object",
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="name",
 *                     description="Update",
 *                     type="string",
 *                 ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="type",
 *                     description="Update",
 *                     type="string",
 *                 ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="price",
 *                     description="Update",
 *                     type="string",
 *                 ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                     property="image",
 *                     description="Update",
 *                     type="file",
 *                 ),
 *              ),
 *          ),
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="successful operation",
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *         response=400,
 *         description="Invalid user supplied"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=404,
 *         description="User not found"
 *     ),
 *      security={{ "bearer": {} }}
 * )
 *
 */

public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id){
    /* Gate::authorize('update', $product); */
    $product = Product::find($id);
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        if (isset($product->image)) {
            Storage::delete($product->image);
        }

        $path = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
    }

    $product->update([
        "name"  => $request->name,
        "type"  => $request->type,
        "price" => $request->price,
        "image" => $path ?? $product->image
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'The choosen product updated successfully',
        'product' => $product,
    ]);
}
```

> **this error in swagger**

> *Failed to fetch.
> Possible Reasons:
> CORS
> Network Failure
> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.*
>
> **This error in postman**

```
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "type": [
        "The type field is required."
    ],
    "price": [
        "The price field is required."
    ],
    "image": [
        "The image field is required."
    ]
}
```

> 

> Here I delete the element from database

```
/**
 * @OA\Delete(
 *      path="/api/product/{id}",
 *      tags={"Products"},
 *      summary="Show the choosen element",
 *      operationId="destroy",
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="id",
 *         in="path",
 *         description="Status values that needed to be considered for filter",
 *         required=true,
 *         explode=true,
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *             default="1",
 *             type="string",
 *         )
 *     ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="successful operation",
 *      ),
 *      security={{ "bearer": {} }}
 * )
 *
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'product deleted successfully',
        'product' => $product,
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Please put your question not only in the title but as an introduction to your question as well. Furthermore it seems the actual error message is missing, which would be important before posting your code.

Comment: _"Please put your question not only in the title"_ ... and leave your "live story" _out_ of the title at the same time. Please go read [ask].

Comment: And quote formatting is for when you actually quote someone or something; it's purpose is not to make your own text "look more interesting" ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to a postman error it looks like that it can't get fields (name,type...) from the request. dd request object and see what's coming.

Comment: I find it easy to use post mehod instead of put in swagger route section then after generation swagger it worked well